# Sensitivity of Inrush Current Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, ltspice, inrush-current

I'm new to LTSpice and analog design - I'm having a bit of a struggle getting a feel for the behavior of this inrush limiting circuit.  Stole the design from another SE post, but playing with the values, it looks to me like the PMOS control is super sensitive to the values of C8 and C10 and the rise time of V1.  Is this true - or am I misunderstanding how these circuits work?

I also don't know what an appropriate amount of inrush current should be.  Can I get away with 7A, or do I need to try harder to reduce the inrush current? (I'd be connecting a couple buck converters to VOut).

I also added some parasitic inductance and a TVS on the input, as well as a reverse polarity diode.  I don't have any best practices with regard how these things work, so I'm open to being schooled if I'm approaching this in the wrong way.

[image: Circuit and Voltage-Current Plots]

Comment: if your model is right you should be able to see the inrush current, it can be up to 25 times the nominal current of your device, this is for a very short time. Test your model first without any limiting circuit and observe the current you are trying to suppress to begin with.

Comment: In addition to what @Juan said, also plot the power dissipation across various elements.

Comment: Flawed circuit: Quiescent gate-to-source voltage exceeds *absolute maximum rating* of +/-20V. Perhaps changing R7 to two resistors (voltage divider) might help drive the gate with voltage within range.

Comment: Inrush is also very important with respect to your power source.  If you dump a bunch of excess unintended current from the source, it can limit and the voltage will droop and that can cause problems.  For example, if there's another device connected to the same source or even if there's a reset supervisor or UVLO (under voltage lockout) protection chip, turning on or hotplugging your device could freeze/reset your whole system.